# Multicore simulation in gem5 simulator: How it works

Tags: cpu-architecture

I want to simulate multicore simulation in gem5. where each program running in each core. For that I use following command with an expectation that different program running in different threads in different cores -

```
 build/ALPHA/gem5.opt --stats-file=output.txt configs/example/se.py --smt "--options=/testcase_path/cccp.in -o /testcase_path/cccp.s; /testcase_path/integrate.in -o /testcase_path/integrate.s" --cpu-type=DerivO3CPU --caches -c "executable1;executable2"
```

My question is  - is it the correct command?

Comment: It might be helpful if you add gem5 to your questions tags.